# Flask APIs all routes 404

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get up and running with Flask. The server is coming up but I am facing 404 in my 2 routes that are all the routes I have. Following is the folder structure:

```
project/
    -> __init__.py
    -> app.py
    -> requirements.txt
    -> api/
        -> __init__.py
        -> routes.py
    -> service
        -> __init__.py
        -> service.py
```

Following is my `app.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

from project.api import api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api/v1')

# Environment based Configuration
host = os.getenv('HOST') or '0.0.0.0'
port = os.getenv('PORT') or '8000'
debug = os.getenv('DEV') or False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug)
```

In my `api/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

from project.api import api
```

In my `routes.py`:

```
from flask import jsonify, request, url_for
from project.service import converter
from project import app


def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


@app.route("/site-map")
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))


@app.route('/hello)
def hello():
    return jsonify({"message": "hello"})
```

This is the log I get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2020 21:04:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2020 21:04:53] "GET /api/v1/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2020 21:05:01] "GET /api/v1/site-map HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Please share the complete route you are trying to acess in your browser.

Comment: @ChristianH trying to access `http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/site-map`

Comment: Thanks @mifol68042 
Plz check the comments in my answer. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are following **Miguel Grinberg**'s approach in his post  https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure

in `api/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

# from project.api import api
from project.api import routes  # -- HERE --
```

in your `routes.py`:

```
from flask import jsonify, request, url_for
from project.service import converter

# from project import app
from project.api import api  # -- HERE --

[..]

# @app.route("/site-map")
@api.route("/site-map")  # -- HERE --
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))


# @app.route('/hello')  #  you are missing "'"
@api.route('/hello')  # -- HERE --
def hello():
    return jsonify({"message": "hello"})
```

Comment: With above changes, I am facing this error - `Traceback (most recent call last):

File "src/app.py", line 4, in <module>

from project.api import api

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

Answer (score 0):

If you check [Flask Blueprint docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) you will see that your imports are missing something.

#### Create blueprint with blueprint routes:

Your `routes.py` be your blueprint.

```py
from flask import jsonify, request, url_for
from project.service import converter
from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


@api.route("/site-map")
def site_map():
    links = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))


@api.route('/hello)
def hello():
    return jsonify({"message": "hello"})
```

#### Import blueprint and register it.

**`app.py`:**

```py
import os
from flask import Flask
from project.api.routes import api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api/v1')

# Environment based Configuration
host = os.getenv('HOST') or '0.0.0.0'
port = os.getenv('PORT') or '8000'
debug = os.getenv('DEV') or False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug)
```

Also you are missing a quote on `@app.route('/hello)`... correct is `@app.route('/hello')`

Comment: I am getting the following error - `Traceback (most recent call last):

File "src/app.py", line 3, in <module>

from project.api.routes import api

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

Comment: please run from your project **root** folder: `python project/app.py`.   .

Also try `from .api.routes import api`, try to run again.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `from api.routes import api`

Comment: @mifol68042 what's your python version? are you using any virtualenv?